# XSLT how to select particular attribute on current node containing multiple attributes without using variables

Tags: xslt

I'm very new to XSL, I'm trying to get the count of particular attribute on current node which has multiple attributes in it without using variable for below XML:

```
<Detail   DetailKey="11119612" DetailNo="123456" DetailType="A">
    <Infos>
        <Info InfoKey="11111599613" SRNo="1" Class="C">
            <NameID NameID="121212" />
        </Info>
        <Info InfoKey="11111599612" SRNo="2" Class="A" Student="N">
            <NameID NameID="121213" />
        </Info>     
    </Infos>
    <Addresss>
        <Address AddressKey="11111591234" SRNo="1" >
            <NameID NameID="121212" />
        </Address>
        <Address AddressKey="11111593243" SRNo="2" >
            <NameID NameID="121213" />
        </Address>      
    </Addresss>
</Detail>
```

I want to check if current node has attribute Student = 'N' or not without using variable. Also the X-Path expression for the same.

I'm trying something like this:

```
<xsl:if(count(//Detail//info[@Student='N']) &gt; 0)">PRINT</xsl:if>
```

But this didn't work. 
When I tried the same for first attribute it worked fine:`<xsl:if(count(//Detail//info[@InfoKey='11111599612']) &gt; 0)">PRINT</xsl:if>`
Same thing I'm not able to apply on second, third and fourth attribute.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, could you provide a sample of your desired output? That might help.

Comment: If you simply want to check if there are any, you don't need to check if count > 0, you just need to check for the existence of any appropriate element. Like: `<xsl:if test="//Detail//info[@Student='N']">PRINT</xsl:if>`

Comment: Note also that your syntax for `xsl:if` is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear.

> I want to check if current node has attribute Student = 'N' or not
>   without using variable.

To check if the **current node** (`Info`?) has an attribute named `Student` with the value of `"N"`, you can test for:

```
<xsl:if test="@Student='N'">
    <!-- then do something -->
</xsl:if>
```

There is probably a better way to accomplish your ultimate goal, but you didn't tell us what it is. In most cases, you would use:

```
<xsl:template match="Info[@Student='N']">
    <!-- do something -->
</xsl:template>
```

to process the `Info` nodes that satisfy the condition.

---

### **Added:**

> I'm trying to flag NameID nodes that have @NameID='121213' and their
>   parent Info has @Student='N'

In such case, you should make your test=`"@NameID='121213' and ../@Student='N'"`.

For example, the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="NameID">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:if test="@NameID='121213' and ../@Student='N'">ABC</xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input example, will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Detail DetailKey="11119612" DetailNo="123456" DetailType="A">
   <Infos>
      <Info InfoKey="11111599613" SRNo="1" Class="C">
         <NameID NameID="121212"/>
      </Info>
      <Info InfoKey="11111599612" SRNo="2" Class="A" Student="N">
         <NameID NameID="121213">ABC</NameID>
      </Info>
   </Infos>
   <Addresss>
      <Address AddressKey="11111591234" SRNo="1">
         <NameID NameID="121212"/>
      </Address>
      <Address AddressKey="11111593243" SRNo="2">
         <NameID NameID="121213"/>
      </Address>
   </Addresss>
</Detail>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Michael and Flynn. 
Basically in my case I'm testing for 2 conditions. I want to write some text when InfoKey="11111599612" and Student="N". 
When both the conditions are satisfied "ABC" text needs to be written. When InfoKey attribute is present I also want to check if Student attribute is also present in the CURRENT NODE hence I have taken the count of the second one.

Comment: I'm trying with: 
<xsl:when test="($InfoKey='11111599612') and (count(//Detail//info[@Student='N']) &gt; 0)">ABC</xsl:when> 
But here this condition is satisfied every time, as the second condition is present in XML. I want check specifically to see if the CURRENT NODE has the attribute.
My requirements is something like I need to check the second attribute as well along with the first one only. Hence I said in the above post it's without using variable.

Comment: @KRS Please don't post code in comments. If you need to clarify your question, edit it and add these clarification there. --- Why wouldn't `test="@InfoKey='11111599612' and @Student='N'"` work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, will surely consider for the next time. Please bare with me as I'm new to XSL. I just checked why didn't the `test="@InfoKey='11111599612' and @Student='N'"` work for me. Seems like I'm trying to access that when it is at the child node of **info** i.e., **NameID**. So I just tried with `<xsl:when test="($NameID='121213') and (count(//Detail//info[../@Student='N']) &gt; 0)">ABC</xsl:when>`
But this didn't work :(

Comment: @KRS That makes no sense. If `NameID` is the current node, you should be testing for: `test="../@InfoKey='11111599612' and ../@Student='N'"`.

Comment: Ok. This works for me partially. What if I need to have a condition like: `test="@NameID='121213' and ../@Student='N'"`? Does this make sense?

Comment: @KRS It makes sense **if** you are trying to flag `NameID` nodes that have @NameID='121213' and their parent `Info` has @Student='N'. In the given example, that would be the 2nd `NameID` of the four listed.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm looking forward, I'm trying to flag `NameID` nodes that have `@NameID='121213'` and their parent `Info` has `@Student='N'`. As a output for this I only need 2nd `NameID`. But `<xsl:when test="@NameID='121213' and ../@Student='N'">ABC</xsl:when>`is not working for the me, the text ABC is not returned.

Comment: But this isn't working for me: `<xsl:when test="@NameID='121213' and ../@Student='N'">ABC</xsl:when>`

Comment: @KRS You said it was working... Have a look at the addition to my post.